# Marshalling structs with non-aligned arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, marshalling, memory-alignment

I get an exception when trying to marshal this structure

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Pack = 1)]
public struct Data
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.U1)]
    [FieldOffset(0x1)]
    public byte[] a2;
}
```

It says
"Could not load type 'WTF.Data' from assembly 'WTF, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because it contains an object field at offset 1 that is incorrectly aligned or overlapped by a non-object field."

When I change offset 1 to 0 or 4, everything is ok.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you attempting to have it at 0x1?

Comment: It is an example. I need to read a struct where byte array is not aligned to 4

Comment: Interop with C++ DLL forwarding data structures directly from hardware requires misaligned arrays, but while browsing SO it's hard to believe for most C# devs someone could need that.

Answer (score 5):

The [StructLayout] affects both the managed and the marshaled layout of the struct.  Bit of a quirk in .NET but creating blittable structs is a rather big win on interop and the CLR can't ignore the fact that managed code always runs on an entirely unmanaged operating system.  Not having to create a copy of a struct but just being able to pass a pointer to the managed version is a very major perf win.

Your [FieldOffset] value violates a very strong guarantee of the .NET memory model, object reference assignments are always atomic.  An expensive word that means that another thread can never observe an invalid object reference that is only partially updated.  Atomicity requires proper alignment, to a multiple of 4 in 32-bit mode, of 8 in 64-bit mode.  It they are misaligned then the processor may need to perform multiple memory bus cycles to glue the bytes together.  That's bad, it causes *tearing* when another thread is also updating the variable.  Getting parts of the pointer value from the old value, part from the new.  What's left is a corrupted pointer that crashes the garbage collector.  Very bad.

Obscure stuff from the high-level point of view of C#, it is however very important to provide basic execution guarantees.  You can't get it misaligned to 1, no workaround as long as you use LayoutKind.Explicit.  So don't use it.

Comment: I just noticed that if we add a dummy byte at the beginning and use `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]`, it does seem to be possible to misalign it. `Marshal.SizeOf = 5` and `Marshal.OffsetOf(a2) = 1`. Not a good thing to do then I suppose?

Comment: @Chris - Maybe that's an acceptable workaround for the OP.  No idea really, he didn't explain why he wanted to use LayoutKind.Explicit.  You ought to post it as an answer, I just focused on the "why does it not work" part.

Comment: What's your take on the `unsafe` alternative? Am I right in thinking that it's a special case where the array isn't actually a reference type/`System.Array`?

Comment: @Chris - Going back to the basics, I think the OP should stop trying to pretend that computers start counting at 1 instead of 0.  His declaration doesn't make any sense, he got the "you are doing it wrong" exception for it.  A bit obfuscated, Microsoft did assume a valid attempt at getting it right to formulate the error message.  Trying to come up with an alternative for senseless code is pretty easy, there are many more things that make sense :)

Comment: Hehe, yeah I'd have to agree with you on that one.

Answer (score 3):

Please see Hans Passant's answer first - aligned data is a good thing, and the CLR enforces it for a reason. It does seem to be possible to "cheat" though, if you for some reason really need or want to:

```
[StructLayout( LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1 )]
public struct Data
{            
    public byte Dummy;

    [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4,
                ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.U1 )]
    public byte[] a2;
}
```

It is also possible with `unsafe` code:

```
[StructLayout( LayoutKind.Explicit, Pack = 1 )]
public unsafe struct Data
{
    [FieldOffset( 1 )]
    public fixed byte a2[4];
}
```

But again, probably not a good idea.

Edit: A third option would be to simply make the array 5 bytes long and have it at offset 0, and then just ignore the first byte. This does seem safer.

Comment: Thanks everybody. I needed to read badly aligned struct from process memory. As I was unable do documentate all of it's fields I was trying to use explicit layout. Now I know it's a bad idea. Got to use sequential layout with 1-byte packing an create placeholders for unknown fields.However working with unions will not be so clean